# 2 JMenu Questions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I know this might be a little "basic" but I've looked at every tutorial possible, and they don't tell me.

So Question 1:

I am trying to put a link in the JMenuBar, how about would I go on doing that?

Question 2:

When I try to add something to a menu bar, it doesn't add it.

I have all of my imports right and I get 0 errors, so why is it not letting me?

Code:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();    

    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(mb);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    mb.add(file);
```

Comment: This adds a JMenu "File" to your JMenuBar. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: What kind of a link do you want in your JMenuBar?

Comment: @user1291492 Like a link to go to different sites, such as google or whatnot.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) It is best to limit questions to ..one question per question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can add JMenuItem to JMenuBar. I don't think you can add a file on JMenuBar. And you can listener on JMenuItem and link to wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to click on a menu item to open a link in a web browser, first create a method that will do this - [`browse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) a URL in your browser, test it from your main method, then you can create `JMenuItem`s and set an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) that will call your method